# Is it possible to specify seperate Firefox and IE height?

Tags: css, firefox

I have two tables that need to line up side by side.  In order to achieve this I have to specify a `td` height.

In IE the height should be 2.1em.  In Mozilla it needs to be 1.76em.

There does not appear to be a

`-moz-height:1.76em;`

Any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the IE height into a separate stylesheet and load it after the default one, using IE-conditional comments so the other browsers ignore it. Otherwise, you can use jQuery to change the height after it's loaded (if ($.browser.msie))

Comment: This works great.  With IE.css listed last combined with the conditional, I only had to add my "exception" to the IE.css. No other modifications required thus little to no code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. For Fire Fox do this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    //Your css here
    #my-id { font-size: 100%; }
}
```

For IE you can do something like this:

```
[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="DefaultSTyleForIE8.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/><![endif]
```

This css will only work for IE 8

Answer (score 2):

in mozilla it is possible to change the height for mozilla by height: **-moz-calc(470px);**
and auto height by **height: -moz-available;**

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Setting `td > * { height: 100% }` sets the height of every cell's contents to the height of the tallest, keeping them together nicely, in every browser but Firefox.  Setting `td { height: -moz-available }` fixes this in Firefox without breaking it in others.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/#thesource)  method,

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

then you can target ie in your css like,

```
.oldie #myel{
    height: 2.1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would shamelessly use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<style>
td {
    height: 1.76em;
}
</style>

<!-- [if IE]>
<style>
td {
    height: 2.1em;
}
<style>
<!endif-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of CSS filters by browser:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter

Answer (score 1):

Browser detect IE using IE's conditional comments and write out separate BODY tags:

```
<!--[if IE]><body class="ie"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
```

Then whenever you have a style, you can be more specific by adding the ie class to over-ride only IE:

```
.mystyle {styles for good browsers}
.ie .mystyle {styles for IE}
```